# Linux Fedora 20: how to deal with a partial internet connection.?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora

I have previously asked for help with this on the "Unix and Linux" site as the question "Linux Fedora 20: how do I deal with “ import read failed(2)”?" (I got there after a lot of floundering about). Although several kind people suggested things to try, none of them solved the problem. Details are in that question so I will not repeat them here, but I am now convinced that there is a deeper underlying fault that needs correction.

I had installed Fedora 20 on a new PC, put together for me by a local vendor, who installed Windows XP3 for me and left a big partition for Linux. All went well, with a dual boot ok, until I tried to install emacs with `yum install emacs` (after `su` of course.) I got a stream of error messages, all ending with `... [Error 14] curl#6 - "could not resolve host: mirror ..."`, and the same thing happened for `gcc` and whatever else I tried to install

With no idea what this meant I posted several questions, and searched the 'net, but none of the proffered solutions worked. In the end I tried installing openSUSE instead, but got a very similar result with `zypper install emacs`. I went back to Fedora 20 again.

So the fault was not specific to the distro. Today I ran `jounalctl` and got this, which may be the clue:  `Failed to open private bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1000/dbus/user_bus_socket:`.

Also, the internet connection works perfectly for browsing, email etc in both Windows and Linux F20 on this dual boot machine, with a wired connection to a BT Homehub 3 Router, and on two Windows laptops with wireless connections.

I have no experience with or knowledge of the system at this level, so, please, can anyone help me -- I have now spent four desperate weeks struggling with it.

---

Thanks andrej for your comment "seems like proxy for browsing but not for curl/wget usage." That sounds good to a non-expert, but I don't know how to deal with it, please could you or someone expand the explanation, and give the details to help me to proceed?

Comment: seems like proxy for browsing but not for curl/wget usage.

Comment: While yum is struggling/stalled, can you load new webpages in your browser?